# the animation keep running when the button is no longer pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the integer value is still one and the animation keep running.
i dont know whats wrong.

Animator :

AnyState -> Jump (condition : "Jumping" equals to 1)

Jump -> Transition (condition: "Jumping" equals to 0)

has exit time = uncheked

i tried changing the Keycode and the GetKey to GetKeyDown still not working.

expected result : Jumping = 0

```
//6 Jumping Animation
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
        anim.SetInteger("Jumping", 1);
        moveDir.y = 2;
        moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);

    }
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
{
    anim.SetInteger("Jumping", 0);
    movementSpeed = 5f;

}
```

Comment: change second if to else if and give it a try.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me answer my own question :D

jumping state is waiting for the player to touch the ground again.
so if you use GetKeyUp. Rather the animation has exit time, or the animation not started properly because the jump key is going up while the player is still on the air.
so to fix that is simple. wait for seconds then turn off the animation.

here is the code :

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){

    StartCoroutine(jumping(2f)); //set time delay to 2 seconds before the anim stop

}

private IENumerator jumping(float Time){
anim.SetInterger("Jumping",1);
moveDir.y = 1;
moveDir *= Speed; //your movement speed value
moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir); //set local value of moveDir to world
yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time); //adjust the delay of your animation to stop
anim.SetInterger("Jumping",0) //Jumping animation stop after time delay
moveDir = new Vector3(0,0,0); //reset the Vector 3 to zero
}
```

thats it